# Designing Polymorphic One-to-many relationship database. Flask

Tags: python, database, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am looking to create polymorphic one-to-many relationship like for example [here](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/upload/one-to-many-poly-relationship-laravel.png?ezimgfmt=ng%3Awebp%2Fngcb6%2Frs%3Adevice%2Frscb7-1) It's hard for me to explain, so let me use example:

Let's say we have three tables **Books, Magazines, Newspapers**, all of them have columns titled **title and text**. The **text column have multiple translations** which I would like to store via **polymorphic one-to-many relationship**.

Concept in SQL-Alchemy:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "books"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String)
    # text_translations = db.relationship("Description", backref="book")


class Magazine(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "magazines"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String)
    # text_translations = db.relationship("Description", backref="book")


class Newspaper(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "newspapers"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String)
    # text_translations = db.relationship("Description", backref="book")


class Translation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "translations"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    # source_type =  # This supposed to be either Book, Magazine, Newspaper
    # source_id =  # This suppossed to be id of the Book/Magazine/Newspaper (depends on source_type)
    language = db.Column(db.String)  # this chooses language
    text = db.Column(db.String)  # this is the text in said language
```

Of course, there is an option to make Translation class looking like this:

```
class Translation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "translations"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    book_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Book.id))
    magazine_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Magazine.id))
    newspaper_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Newspaper.id))
    language = db.Column(db.String)  # this chooses language
    text = db.Column(db.String)  # this is the text in said language
```

However, In case there would be way much more tables than 3 that wouldn't be efficient.
I tried doing it via SQLAlchemy, but I am not sure if that's even possible if there is really no way of doing it in SQLAlchemy which alternative can I use?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. You can try this modified code

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from sqlalchemy.orm import generic_relationship

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Translation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "translations"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    source_type = db.Column(db.String) 
    source_id = db.Column(db.Integer)  
    language = db.Column(db.String)  
    text = db.Column(db.String)  

class Content(db.Model):
    __abstract__ = True
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String)
    translations = generic_relationship(Translation, source_type, source_id)

class Book(Content):
    __tablename__ = "books"

class Magazine(Content):
    __tablename__ = "magazines"

class Newspaper(Content):
    __tablename__ = "newspapers"
```

Comment: This didn't work for me since generic_relationship isn't the part of sqlalchemy.orm - I've found generic_relationship from sqlalchemy_utils which allowed me to design translation table with source_type and source_id, however I still haven't figured out how can I populate its data back to book, magazine, newspaper

Answer (score 0):

I've managed to fix this issue with this [guide](https://hackmd.io/@chrisoney/rkNWNTt_d) here is how classes I've mentioned supposed to look like (skipped Newspapers class):

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, fields, marshal, request
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import ENUM


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:///database.db"
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class Translation(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "translations"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    object_id = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    object_type = db.Column(ENUM('book', 'magazine', name='object_types'), nullable=False)
    language = db.Column(db.String)
    text = db.Column(db.String)

class Book(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "books"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String)
    translations = db.relationship(
        'Translation',
        primaryjoin="and_(Translation.object_type == 'book', foreign(Translation.object_id) == Book.id)",
        lazy='dynamic'
    )

class Magazine(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "magazines"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    author = db.Column(db.String)
    translations = db.relationship(
        'Translation',
        primaryjoin="and_(Translation.object_type == 'book', foreign(Translation.object_id) == Magazine.id)",
        lazy='dynamic'
    )

with app.app_context():
    db.create_all()
```